# How to Get MQTT Topic name coming from AWS IOT CORE to AWS Lambda .Net Core

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot-core

I need to get Topic name in AWS Lambda. I can't insert the serial machine into payload, but only on the naming of publish topic.

Comment: I need a topic details that iot core publish message on mqtt topic in lambda function which trigger aws iot core.